# could not detect network error when try to deploy

Tags: hardhat, hardhat-deploy, goerli

```
require('dotenv').config();
require('@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox');

const API_URL = process.env.API_URL;
const PRIVATE_KEY = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY;
const API_KEY=process.env.API_KEY

console.log("API_URL:", API_URL);
console.log("PRIVATE_KEY:", PRIVATE_KEY);
console.log("API_KEY:", API_KEY);
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.18",
  networks: {
    goerli: {
      url: `https://eth-goerli.g.alchemy.com/v2/iX13YM9rvs66xWAlxXXWY13ottte2${API_KEY}`,
      accounts: [PRIVATE_KEY],
    },
  },
};
```

when i try to deploy using goerli i am getting error as notdefined Error: could not detect network (event="noNetwork", code=NETWORK_ERROR, version=providers/5.7.2)
local deployment is working fine

reason: 'could not detect network',
code: 'NETWORK_ERROR',

Answer (score 0):

The error in your code seems to be in the URL string. You might have a typo or an incorrect value in the URL. Update the URL with the correct value.

```
url: `https://eth-goerli.alchemyapi.io/v2/${API_KEY}`,
```

This assumes you're using Alchemy as your Ethereum node provider. Replace ${API_KEY} with the actual API key if you're not using environment variables.